# AIR application fails to install on BlackBerry Playbook

Tags: apache-flex, air, blackberry-playbook, flex-mobile

I'm trying to install an AIR mobile (flex) application on BlackBerry Playbook.
The application failed to installed with this following error message " failure 821 Application-requires-system :**unrecognized system name "BlackBerry10"**

I am using AIR 3.1 SDK and I am using Adobe and Blackberry ANEs to build the app.

Is the AIR SDK I am using (3.1) is correct for Playbook ? It DOES work for all other BlackBerry device.. ?
Any ideas what might cause this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIR doesn't officially support BlackBerry 10, only the previous generation (BlackBerry 8, I think?). AIR 3.1 is nearly 2 years old at this point, too, so it doesn't support much of anything. Adobe stopped developing for Blackberry in 3.4 or 3.5, I believe. The only way to develop for BlackBerry 10 is to use the third-party SDKs for AIR provided by BlackBerry itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your app with the [BlackBerry PlayBook AIR SDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/air/) and not the one for BlackBerry 10. I had the same issue some time ago.

(Also I'm not sure if AIR 3.1 is supported, I think it's only AIR 3 or AIR 2.7)