# Is it possible to develope AIR applications for Playbook?

Tags: apache-flex, blackberry, air

Is there any way to develop AIR Mobile applications for Playbook ?
I managed to develop an app for all other BlackBerry devices, but I can't build for Q10.
I am using FlashBuilder 4.7

Comment: Have you had a look round the BB10 Air microsite?  http://developer.blackberry.com/air/

Comment: possible duplicate of [AIR application fails to install on BlackBerry Playbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707841/air-application-fails-to-install-on-blackberry-playbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You need the SDK and optional plugin for Flash Builder (eclipse) Supprt.

https://developer.blackberry.com/air/

Comment: As I said, I have the SDK and managed to develop apps for all BlackBerry phones except the PlayBook - There's a problem with AIR there, and I don't know what. What is the optional plugin ?

Comment: The Playbook is listed as a supported device, but I don't have one so I've never been able to test it. I just have a regular BB phone for testing. If you are having an issue with it, I suggest you give more info or ask a specific question relating to the issue.